# Access Device db on another device in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having a folder named "Import Export" on my sdcard on my phone, which contains csv files with data which I am trying to import into my android app's database.

It's getting imported and even showing the data. But when I try to launch it on another device the database is empty.

I thought that once I have imported the data, the data should be saved in my database and would output the data when i try to launch the app on another device.

What could be the possible problem, that it is not doing so?

Comment: each device has his own database, there is no link from one device db to another.

Comment: thanks for replying. Then how do i display data in other device using database of my app that i have created in eclipse

Comment: thats a very diff question, your db should be in central place which you can query through API services.

Comment: sorry for that, actually i am new to android programming, so am not able to figure it out as to how this thing works. So if u can please elaborate

Comment: no problem, have you ever worked on server side languages? like php ?

Comment: it was around 2 years ago.

Comment: This a very good tutorial here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

first conver your csv file to db or sqlite using **SQLite Database Browser** and than paste this file into your **assets** folder of your project and than on create of your **Application** or **Activity** write it in the Data folder/directory of your app property and so that you can get your Database on each device. If you need any further help please let me know, I feel happy to help you.